# Get index seek instead of scan in paging temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

I've created a temporary table for testing I've primary key on intindex.

When I do `select * from #TmpDashboard where intindex = 1` I get index seek.

but when I apply paging formula I get index scan which causing performance issues.

```
Declare @Currentpage      INT = 1
      ,@Pagesize         INT = 10

select * from #TmpDashboard 
WHERE  (@Pagesize = 0 OR (intIndex BETWEEN ((@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize) + 1 AND (@CurrentPage * @PageSize))) --gives index scan
```

How can i convert above formula to get index seek.

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan? How many rows do you have in `#TmpDashboard`and how many qualify for `intIndex BETWEEN ((@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize) + 1 AND (@CurrentPage * @PageSize))`?

Comment: @MartinK. just checked sick or scan not number of rows!

Comment: The data retrieval method depends on the data you have. If there are too many rows which match the condition a table scan is more efficient than an index.

Comment: @MartinK. value will be always 1.

Comment: Try adding a covering index.

Comment: Which value do you mean?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008+ `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` can help.

Comment: Are you sure this is not generating a *range* scan? With indexes, for equality it can perform an index seek. For inequalities (and BETWEEN translates to ">= and <=") it must perform an index range scan. It must determine where the search starts and where it ends. That's still better than a complete index scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "OR" in the WHERE clause is causing the scan because it makes the statement nondeterministic.  I would suggest to set a second set of variables that you can use to simplify the query, like this:

```
 Declare @Currentpage      INT = 1
      ,@Pagesize         INT = 10;

declare @start int = Case when @pagesizee = 0 then 0 else ((@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize) + 1 end
, @end int = case when @pagesize > 0 then @CurrentPage * @PageSize else (select max(intindex) from #tmpdashboard) end

select * from #TmpDashboard 
WHERE  intindex between @start and @end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #TmpDashboard (intindex int primary key)
select * from #TmpDashboard where intindex = 1
Declare @Currentpage INT, @Pagesize INT;
select  @Currentpage= 1, @Pagesize = 10;

select * from #TmpDashboard 
WHERE  intIndex BETWEEN ((@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize) + 1 AND (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)
drop table #TmpDashboard
```